# adb command in cmd file (windows)

Tags: android, shell, batch-file, cmd, adb

I have command and she working fine in cmd in manual mode:

```
adb shell
su
echo 'AT+EGMR=1,7,"558378919678440"' > /dev/radio/pttycmd1
```

How do I run this command in a .bat file?
I tried such options, but they do not work:

```
adb shell su -с echo 'AT+EGMR=1,7,"558378919678440"' > /dev/radio/pttycmd1
adb shell "su -с 'echo 'AT+EGMR=1,7,"558378919678440"' > /dev/radio/pttycmd1'"
adb shell su "-с echo 'AT+EGMR=1,7,"558378919678440"' > /dev/radio/pttycmd1"
```

Please help.

Comment: That looks like BASH code.  The batch-file tag is for Windows Batch files.

Comment: @Alex P. Why did you rollback the tag changes?

Comment: @ScottBeeson, because the original tags were appropriate and people who removed those did not understand the issue.

Comment: @AlexP., the 1st set of commands is running adb interactive shell in CMD? And the 2nd set is in a batch-file? Just for understanding for those who do not know.

Answer (score -1):

Using `bash` you can run this command

```
adb shell su root sh -c $'"echo \'AT+EGMR=1,7,\\"558378919678440\\"\' > /dev/radio/pttycmd1"'
```

So, if you are running it from a batch file you may need to invoke bash first

Comment: friend, im tried this command, im have this: /system/bin/sh: can't create /dev/radio/pttycmd1: **Permission denied**

Comment: now i have with error: /system/bin/sh: no closing quote